# Why I get error message PLS-0382:expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I am little bit confusing and I have no idea what is wrong in my function.

```
FUNCTION GET_USERS_WITHOUT_ADMINS(busyUserId IN NUMBER)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*getUsersWithoutAdmins*/
BEGIN
IF (busyUserId) THEN
OPEN rc FOR
    SELECT u.UserID,
      CONCAT(CONCAT(u.Surname, ' '),u.Lastname) AS  UserName,      
      u.Mobile,
      u.Email,
      u.Type,
      u.Status, 
      COUNT(u.UserID) as Count, 
      ur.Roles
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
    ON u.User_roleID = ur.id
    WHERE u.User_roleID NOT IN (1) 
    AND u.Surname IS NOT NULL 
    AND u.Lastname IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY u.UserID,u.Mobile, u.Email,u.Type, u.Status,  ur.Roles,u.Surname,u.Lastname;
ELSE 
OPEN rc FOR
    SELECT u.UserID,
       CONCAT(CONCAT(u.Surname, ' '),u.Lastname) AS  UserName,
       u.Mobile,
       u.Email,
       u.Type,
       u.Status, 
       COUNT(u.UserID) as Count, 
       ur.Roles  
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
    ON u.User_roleID = ur.id 
    WHERE u.Surname IS NOT NULL 
    AND u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY u.UserID,u.Mobile, u.Email,u.Type, u.Status,  ur.Roles,u.Surname,u.Lastname;
END IF;
RETURN rc;
END GET_USERS_WITHOUT_ADMINS;
```

I suppost the error comes from `bussyUserID` and I try to change from `IF` to `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN bussyUserID THEN 

.....
```

But somehow I againg get same error message. Does anyone know where the error comes from ? Where did I made mistake ?

Comment: busyUserId is a number, so you have to compare it to something when you write 'if busyUserId ....'. Oracle does NOT assume that a value of 0 is FALSE and any other value is TRUE.

Comment: Can I just write IF (bussyUserID) and change datatype to VARCHAR ?

Comment: I believe you want something `IF busyUserId is not null THEN`

Comment: No, I want something IF busyUserID IS TRUE THEN

Comment: To compare something to TRUE, it should be BOOLEAN, not number, nor varchar2, ... The issue is that you cannot use BOOLEAN datatype outside of PLSQL, as it is NOT an Oracle SQL datatype.